# Creating a Zelda-like map in pure C++ not working

Tags: c++

I wanted to create a map like in Zelda, but it keeps showing hashtags instead of 1 on A1 and I don't know why.

```
vector <string> A0 {"#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#"};
vector <string> A1 {"1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"};
vector <string> A2 {"#","#","#","#","#","a","#","#","#","#"};
vector <string> A3 {"#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#"};
vector <string> A4 {"#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#"};
vector <string> A5 {"#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#"};
vector <string> A6 {"#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#"};
vector <string> A7 {"#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#"};
vector <string> A8 {"#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#"};
vector <string> A9 {"#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#"};
int main()
{
    vector <vector<string>> MiniMap {A0,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9};//A0-9 rows
    for (unsigned z=0;z<MiniMap.size();z++)
    {        
      cout<<z<<".";
      for (unsigned i =0;i<MiniMap[z].size();i++)
          cout<<MiniMap[0][i];
      cout<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The idea is that it would show the entire map, but it doesn't work for some reason, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cout<<MiniMap[0][i];
```

Shouldn't it be

```
cout<<MiniMap[z][i];
```

?

Comment: @GabiAxinte no problem! If it worked for you, please approve my answer and make me happy :D